# Adding Guests to Count - CiviEvent

Tags: civievent

The agency I am utilizing CiviCRM for has been doing excel sheets for years for event invitations and RSVP's. Typically, households are invited personally but I only have the head of household name. We also will get RSVP's with just the head of household name and number of tickets they want (no information on guests). From my research I understand that CiviEvent runs on the basis of every guest having a profile, which doesn't work with our model.

Some people have suggested making a custom field for number of additional guests, but this number will not count against the final total, which is not ideal if there is a cap for the event. I was curious what some people have done to get around this, as having unnamed guests is common practice, and will obviously affect final count for ticket sales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with Price Sets you can add a field that is an integer that you can set so that those people are counted as 'attendees' for the sake of counting the number of registrations. You should find some helpful instructions [here](http://book.civicrm.org/user/events/creating-an-event/) but I am not seeing images currently.

You should then be able to use either the front or back end to make a registration for the 'head of household' and then e.g. put 6 in that price set field to have that registration be counted as having 6 attendees.

That may go some way to what you need.

Comment: Thank you! This will be a great solution for a fixed event price. But this particular event gets a discount for pairs of tickets. I played around a bit with other options through the price sets. For now I created a select option for 1 attendee and the price, 2 attendees and the discounted price, and some combinations for 3 and 4 attendees. Not the prettiest but only work around I could find for the discount pricing integration for pairs of tickets. Definitely will use your recommendation though for our other event that has the same price across the board. THANKS!